# Movie where a meteor/asteroid crashes into a lake?

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a movie, where a meteor/asteroid crashed into a lake. It had a chemical or pathogen of some sort that contaminated the water supply of an entire region. That's almost all I remember about it. I remember seeing it on TV back in 2009(might have been Netflix though). Any ideas as to what it was called? It probably wasn't a big budget movie, likely just some crappy low-budget B-movie...

I have heard about a movie called "The Curse" and this is not that movie.

Comment: Roughly when did it seem to have been made? Asking since _The Curse_ is from the 80s but you said you watched that in 2009 :)

Answer (score 1):

Coud this be the (Oscar®-nominated) [Meteor Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_Apocalypse)?

> A long-period comet's orbit is determined to be crossing directly in
>   the path of Earth's orbit. All of the world's nuclear states fire
>   their missiles at the comet, but pieces of the comet continue to
>   strike the Earth, contaminating the groundwater and causing millions
>   to become sick.